# selecting duplicate values with a condition from a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in mysql:

```
Key    DI     CI     FD      FA  NM  Valid_from   Valid_to
 0   1224468 123 2012-06-30  3   6   2013-01-23  9999-12-31
 1   1234567 123 2013-12-31  3   10  2014-02-27  2014-03-10
 2   1234567 123 2013-12-31  2   12  2014-03-10  9999-12-31
 3   1234579 123 2013-12-31  3   12  2014-05-15  9999-12-31
 4   1234595 123 2013-12-31  1   12  2014-06-30  9999-12-31
 5   122469  123 2015-11-11  1   6   2015-11-11  9999-12-31
 6   1224470 123 2015-11-11  2   12  2015-11-11  9999-12-31
 7   1224471 123 2015-11-11  3   15  2015-11-11  9999-12-31
 8   1224472 123 2015-11-10  2   13  2015-11-10  9999-12-31
 9   1224473 123 2015-11-10  3   12  2015-11-10  9999-12-31
```

If there are records which has the same "FD", I need to get the ones which 's "FA" is "1", if exists.

Basically, I want this output.

```
Key   DI     CI     FD      FA  NM  Valid_from   Valid_to
 0  1224468 123 2012-06-30  3   6   2013-01-23  9999-12-31
 4  1234595 123 2013-12-31  1   12  2014-06-30  9999-12-31
 5  122469  123 2015-11-11  1   6   2015-11-11  9999-12-31
 8  1224472 123 2015-11-10  2   13  2015-11-10  9999-12-31
 9  1224473 123 2015-11-10  3   12  2015-11-10  9999-12-31
```

I have tried the following code, but it gives a weird output:

Code:

```
SELECT T1.*
    FROM findoc T1 LEFT JOIN
     findoc T2
    ON DATE(T1.`Financial_date`) = DATE(T2.`Financial_date`) AND T2.`Fig_audit` <> 1
    WHERE  T2.`Fig_audit` IS NULL OR T1.`Fig_audit` = 1
```

Output:

```
Key   DI     CI     FD      FA  NM  Valid_from   Valid_to
 4  1234595 123 2013-12-31  1   12  2014-06-30  9999-12-31
 4  1234595 123 2013-12-31  1   12  2014-06-30  9999-12-31
 4  1234595 123 2013-12-31  1   12  2014-06-30  9999-12-31
 5  122469  123 2015-11-11  1   6   2015-11-11  9999-12-31
 5  122469  123 2015-11-11  1   6   2015-11-11  9999-12-31
```

It looks a complicated query, and I couldn't manage to do it.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your expected results don't show the records that only have FA=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do `case based aggregation` to find out if there exists row with same date and with atleast one row with column value for `FA` as 1

```
select F.* from finddoc F
inner join 
(
select fd , sum( case when fa = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as faOneCount
from finddoc 
group by fd

) T
on (F.FD = T.FD and T.faOneCount = 1 AND F.FA =1)
or ( F.FD = T.FD and T.faOneCount =0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (and I'm not sure I do), you could try something like this:

```
SELECT T1.*
    FROM findoc T1
   where T1.NM in (select distinct NM from findoc where FA = 1);
```

I'm assuming that `NM` is the common field for which you want to return all results if the `FA` for any of those `NM` entries is `1`.  But that could be a wrong assumption.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the answer. But it doesn't work. It gives wrong output. It gives the same table without 0th row.

Comment: What does that mean?  You're not providing much clarity for what you're looking for.  Run the subquery separately and see if that's getting you what you want (it should).  Troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Do you want to see the output? It doesn't give the output as I wanted.